# R: Is there a way to get the sessionInfo/packages of other session R?

Tags: r, session, package

Imagine that I open two session R.

In the first (R1) I loaded the package dplyr.

Now, my questions is, is there way to get the sessionInfo/packages loaded in R1 
through R2??

UPDATE:

I am writing a R help system in Atom editor. Atom editor currently not support the function help of R. So i am creating one. And to find the help of the function you need to search into packages where this function is, the best way is know what packages are loaded in your current session R. And that is my difficult. One way to solution this is to forgett the loaded packages and search in all installed packages, but it is to slowly if you have a lot of packages installed.

So in my script R i have a line that has this code:
    `pkg <- .packages()` # all packages loaded in this currently session

But when I run this script R1 in other script R2, it not get the packages loaded in the currently script R2, but the script R1.

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Comment: I updated, but i am not sure if you understood. My problem is exactly this. How get the packages loaded in other sessio R.

Comment: Would having R1 log its `sessionInfo` to a file accomplish your goal?

Comment: Yes, but i'll need to execute a explicit command in R1 to save this log? Am I right?

Comment: No, you have not understood my request for clarification. I'm interested in the reasons for your question. It's very unusual (except within parallelization frameworks) that you control an R session from another R session. You are doing something unusual and the best answer might be that you should do something else instead. E.g., the answer might be that you should build a package, which would ensure that all needed dependencies are installed and loaded.

Comment: Yes, i am writing a R help system in Atom editor. Atom editor currently not support the function help of R. So i am creating one. And to find the help of the function you are searching, the best way is know what packages are loaded in your current session R. And that is my difficult. One way to solution this is to forgett the loaded packages and search in all installed packages, but it is to slowly if you have a lot of packages installed.

Comment: Please edit this information into your question.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the Services API to interact with Hydrogen

The following details interacting with other packages in atom: http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/interacting-with-other-packages-via-services/

Hydrogen is an interface to a jupyter kernel. It's is maintaining the session with the kernel, and it has a plugin API currently which you could use to get the connection information to the backing kernel. https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/PluginAPI.html.  Using that you could send your call to packages().

There is also r-exec, but I believe that's Mac only.  In that case, you could get the

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i am not an expert in javascript, so i had difficuties to execute it. I am trying to use $ jupiter qtconsole --kernel=ir.